# PyQt5 error: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I upgraded `PyQt4` to `PyQt5` and I use python3. I have the following imports:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

And I have the following main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get parameters
    print("HERE1")
    opts = monGetOpts()
    print("HERE2")
    # Set exceptions and signals handling
    sys.excepthook = monExceptionsHandler
    print("HERE3")
    signal(SIGINT, monSignalsHandler)
    print("HERE4")
    # Launch GUI
    print(sys.argv)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print("HERE5\n")
    style = QStyleFactory.create('windows')
    print("HERE6\n")
    app.setStyle(style)
    myMonitor = MyMonitor(opts['workdir'], opts['refresh'])
    myMonitor.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I added the prints in order to track where the error is coming from and to show it:

```
HERE1
HERE2
HERE3
HERE4
['./mon.py', '-w', '/path/to/work_dir/']
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort
```

I saw there are a lot of threads about this issue but they suggested to use the Linux `ldd` command and I'm not sure its related.
I think it is coming from PyQt5 because it worked with PyQt4. What could be the issue?

**Edit:** I used the `ldd` on the `libqxcb.so` file. The output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff7ffa000)
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007ffff783f000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007ffff7601000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ffff7365000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ffff714f000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007ffff6926000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007ffff669a000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007ffff5f07000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007ffff5c9d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/noelision/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffff5a80000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007ffff587e000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ffff565e000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007ffff5454000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ffff5242000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ffff4f04000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffff4c07000)
libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 (0x00007ffff49ff000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007ffff47c0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffff45bc000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffff4232000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffff401a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff3c75000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffff3a73000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffff3763000)
libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ffff3539000)
libbz2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007ffff332a000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007ffff30ed000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007ffff2ea6000)
libicui18n.so.56 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007ffff2a0d000)
libicuuc.so.56 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007ffff2655000)
libicudata.so.56 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007ffff0c72000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffff7ddb000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007ffff0a6f000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007ffff086c000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007ffff0666000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007ffff0463000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007ffff0235000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007ffff0032000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fffefe2c000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fffefc14000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fffefa0f000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fffef809000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fffef5fa000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fffef3f6000)
libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007fffef1db000)
libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fffeef6c000)
```

**Second EDIT**:

I setenv the `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` to be `1` an rerun the code and got:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...                                                                                                                                       
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"                                                                                                                                           
Found metadata in lib /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=                                                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                           
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",                                                                                
    "MetaData": {                                                                                                                                           
        "Keys": [                                                                                                                                           
            "eglfs"                                                                                                                                         
        ]                                                                                                                                                   
    },                                                                                                                                                      
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",                                                                                                                 
    "debug": false,                                                                                                                                         
    "version": 329473                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                           


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"                                                                                                                                         
Found metadata in lib /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=                                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                           
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",                                                                                
    "MetaData": {                                                                                                                                           
        "Keys": [                                                                                                                                           
            "linuxfb"                                                                                                                                       
        ]                                                                                                                                                   
    },                                                                                                                                                      
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",                                                                                                               
    "debug": false,                                                                                                                                         
    "version": 329473                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                           


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"                                                                                                                                         
Found metadata in lib /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=                                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                           
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",                                                                                
    "MetaData": {                                                                                                                                           
        "Keys": [                                                                                                                                           
            "minimal"                                                                                                                                       
        ]                                                                                                                                                   
    },                                                                                                                                                      
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",                                                                                                               
    "debug": false,                                                                                                                                         
    "version": 329473                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                           


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"                                                                                                                                      
Found metadata in lib /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                           
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",                                                                                
    "MetaData": {                                                                                                                                           
        "Keys": [                                                                                                                                           
            "minimalegl"                                                                                                                                    
        ]                                                                                                                                                   
    },                                                                                                                                                      
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",                                                                                                            
    "debug": false,                                                                                                                                         
    "version": 329473                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                           


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"                                                                                                                                       
Found metadata in lib /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                           
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",                                                                                
    "MetaData": {                                                                                                                                           
        "Keys": [                                                                                                                                           
            "offscreen"                                                                                                                                     
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort
```

I can't reinstall the library, I have to use what IT gave us. Do we need to use `xcb`? Maybe replace it somehow with the other available platforms?
The OS is Linux SLES12

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling PyQt5? how did you install it?

Comment: execute `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and execute again, what is the output?

Comment: @eyllanesc please see my edit

Comment: @vesii what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc Linux SLES12

Comment: @vesii If you check the log you have added, you will see that you are missing "libEGL.so.1", so I recommend you search the repositories of your OS which package has it. Does your OS have a desktop system? How have you installed PyQt5? See https://pkgs.org/download/libEGL.so.1()(64bit)

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I see that the file does not exist. I have not installed it. Its a shared area from IT. Do we need to use "xcb"? Is it possible to not use it?

Comment: You can try using `eglfs`, `linuxfb`, `minimal`, `minimalegl` or `offscreen`  to do this: `python  main.py -platform eglfs`

Comment: @eyllanesc it thinks that `-partform eglfs` is an option of `main.py` and not `python`. It also does not have `-partform` option for `python`

Comment: @vesii It is not an option for python but for Qt/PyQt and if you don't want to run it in the terminal you can add it as an argument to QApplication: `app = QApplication(sys.argv + ["-platform", "eglfs"])`

Comment: @vesii Did it work for you?