# PyQt5: version LIBDBUS_1_3 not defined in file libdbus-1.so.3 with link time reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4

I use python3 and I'm trying to migrate from PyQt4 to PyQt5. I have the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyMonitor(QWidget, mon_ui.Ui_monitor):
    def __init__(self, workdir, refresh, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setupMembers(workdir, refresh)
        # More code ...

    # more methods

if __name__ == "__main__":
    opts = monGetOpts()
    sys.excepthook = monExceptionsHandler
    signal(SIGINT, monSignalsHandler)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    style = QStyleFactory.create('windows')
    app.setStyle(style)
    MyMonitor = MyMonitor(opts['workdir'], opts['refresh'])
    MyMonitor.show()
    app.exec_()
```

For some reason, it fails when getting to the line `self.setupUi(self)`:

```
python3.6.3: relocation error: /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3/modules/r1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5: symbol dbus_message_get_allow_interactive_authorization, version LIBDBUS_1_3 not defined in file libdbus-1.so.3 with link time reference
```

I tried to Google this error message and found out some tickets but they didn't specify how they solved it. Have anybody saw it? How to solve it? How to debug it?

Comment: Is your system updated? What versions of Qt and dbus do you ave installed?

Comment: From [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57677622/984421) on a similar subject, it looks like you should be reporting these problems to your IT dept.

Comment: The system is updated. We use Linux SLES12. The PyQt version is `5.12.3`.

Comment: I've encountered the same error and also can't solve it. Is there any update @versii ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on SLES12. Once I used python 3.7 and restricted the package version to pyqt5<5.12, it worked for me.